# HTML/CSS - Adding abstract shapes as backgrounds

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to build something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp6C6.png), using bootstrap. Currently what I've built is this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>

        .section-1 {
            height: 100vh;
            padding-top: 200px;
            text-align: center;
            background: "fff";
        }

        #shape {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background: yellow;

            -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 24%, 89% 0, 100% 40%, 55% 88%);
            clip-path: polygon(0 24%, 89% 0, 100% 40%, 55% 88%);
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <!-- Intro Section -->
    <section id="tab-1" class="section-1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">

                    <h1><b>UI & UX DESIGN STUDIO</b></h1>
                    <p class="text-right"> <b> UI/UX </b> <i>Design</i></p>
                    <p class="text-right"> <b> Brand Identity</b> <i>Design</i></p>
                    <p class="text-right"> <b> Web & Mobile</b> <i>Development</i></p>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
```

in the above block the id shape is the border shape in the image (one without the solid). How should I add this shape as a background for my content?